# Can the Fubini theorem be applied to a trapezoid?

Tags: measure-theory

I have two questions:

> How does one apply the Fubini theorem?

and

> Can it be applied to a trapezoid?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide way more context to get a (useful) answer. Apply the theorem of fubini to *what*? And what do you mean by a trapeze here?

Comment: I suspect a [trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) was intended.

Comment: 1. Exchange the integrals. 2. Yes.

Comment: My "reopen vote has been recorded" but there's no menu allowing me to choose a reason to reopen.  Nor am I sure whether those who voted to close agreed on the reason to close it.  I began an answer, which I was not allowed to save.  If there are five people for whom it is difficult to tell what is being asked, then maybe their difficulty is _their_ difficulty.

Comment: Don't think so, @MichaelHardy : this really looks like not a real question, with so much context, explanation, ideas, background lacking. I didn't vote to close, but I can see I would easily.

Comment: The question is: How is judiciously chosing the order of integration used to evaluate integrals, and does Fubini's theorem justify changes in the order of integration when the domain of the double integral is a trapezoid rather than the Cartesian product of two sets?  Is it unclear that that's what's being asked?

Comment: I've started a discussion of this question on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/re-opening-a-question-on-fubinis-theorem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fubini's theorem says a double integral (where the integral of the absolute value is finite) is equal to either of two iterated integrals.  One concrete case:
$$
\iint\limits_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} f(x,y)\,d(x,y) = \int_a^b\left(\int_c^d f(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx = \int_c^d \left( \int_a^b f(x,y)\, dx \right) \, dy,
$$
provided that
$$
\iint\limits_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} |f(x,y)|\,d(x,y) <\infty.
$$

One way to use this theorem is to exploit the fact that one of the two iterated integrals may be readily evaluated.

As for trapezoids, here is an example:
$$T=\{(x,y) : 1\le y\le2,\  0\le x\le y \}\tag{1}$$
Suppose one wants
$$
\iint\limits_T e^{y^2} \,d(x,y).
$$
Applying $(1)$, this becomes
$$
\int_1^2 \left( \int_0^y e^{y^2} \, dx \right)\,dy.
$$
This is easily evaluated, whereas if one had integrated first with respect to $y$ and afterward with respect to $x$, one would face the intractable integral $\int e^{y^2}\, dy$.

**Does Fubini's theorem justify this?** The answer is "yes" because one can view the integral as
$$
\iint\limits_{[0,2]\times[1,2]} f(x,y) \, d(x,y)
$$
where
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} e^{y^2} & \text{if }x\le y, \\[10pt] 0 & \text{otherwise}.  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: +1. Up to multiplication by the characteristic function like you did in the end, trapezoid or not, one can always apply Fubini to an integrable function.